# Recommend location for JAR files on OSX

Tags: java, macos, javadoc, osx-mountain-lion

I have a number of libraries (folders of JARs):

- Oracle client 10
- Android SDK
- BusinessObjects Java and WebService SDKs
- Crystal Reports Runtime & Eclipse plugin

A number of these also include the JavaDocs in ZIP format.

I would like to use these libraries w/ Eclipse, NetBeans, and Groovy.

At this point, I've added them to ~/SDKs folder, but I don't really care for this spot.  A colleague suggested that I use the /usr/local directory instead.

To further confuse things, Apple's Technical Q&A document [QA1170 - Important Java Directories on Mac OS X](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1170/_index.html) recommends using one of these folders:

- /Library/Java/Extensions
- ~/Library/Java/Extensions

The document mentions:

> Items placed in either of these directories do not need to be named in
>   an application's classpath and will be available to all applications
>   run under the respective scope (system-level or user-level, depending
>   which directory is used).

I like the idea, but will there been any issues w/ multiple versions of a given library (e.g. Oracle 10 & 11 clients) being located one of these folders?

In general, is there a preferred location for JARs on OS X?  Should the JARs' JavaDoc be contained in the same folder?

Comment: Apache Maven is a fine build tool that can make you free of dependency hell and do all necessary work behind your eyes. Fell free to join build solutions such Apache Maven and Gradle - http://www.gradle.org/ . I hope you'll enjoy that staff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use a proper repository, like [Archiva](http://archiva.apache.org/), for example. And retrieve these artifacts on demand using, say, [Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/).

Another alternative would be to use Amazon S3 as Maven repository.

Comment: I decided to take the red pill.